# How to begin with Realm in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, realm

Can anyone tell me how to begin with Realm DB, I am new to Realm and not able to add a proper dependency of Realm, to begin with it.

I am copying all the dependencies from Realm documentation and their Git Repo, but every time it ends with an error either in `Realm` itself or if somehow I managed to import Realm to my project, another error appears in `Realm.init(this)` and one more thing yesterday when I tried for 5-6 hours, in the end, i did both but then i got an error from build like cannot find realm something something.....

I don't find anything helpful in Realm docs

What I want is, does anyone know how to implement Realm in with proper imports
Just make it through `Realm.init(this) in the Application class` and that should Run without any error

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for coding specific questions; write some code and when you get stuck post the code and troubleshooting as we'll take a look. The Realm Getting Started Guide is pretty thorough [Install Realm - Kotlin SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/install/) and includes overview as well as coding examples. Did you take a look at that?

Comment: Hi user, starting out with a new technology can be frustrating.
It would be helpful if you could provide the exact "something something" error message so that we can better asses the problem and help you.